# Get the keypress code without to care which symbol is clicked using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see here is have few questions when is asking for how can get which key is clicked from keyboard. I tested is ok is working if is in English case.
If I change the language and the symbols on keyboard is changed then is not show anything.

So my question is how can I get the keypress code without to care which language is now used the user when is click the key 'G' or 'Г' or something else.

here is my simple jquery code

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.charCode == 103) {
        alert('g');
    } else if (e.charCode == 71) {
        alert('G');
    }
});
```

If is with english is working, when I change to Bulgarian then is not working. How can I make to working on every language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the solution of my problem. Thanks of this [article](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2009/06/16/ctrl-key-combination-simple-jquery-plugin/)

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(e) {     
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        alert('Echo');
    } else {
        alert(e.which + ' ' + e.key);
    }
});
```

What I'm changing. I change only the event. I replace 'keypress' with 'keydown' and now is the same code without to care which language is used.

Answer (score 0):

Using the keypress event will give you the character typed, regardless of keyboard layout.
For character input, it is suggested you use keypress(), which will report the actual ASCII code for the character pressed. It automatically takes care of letter case, and ignores non-character presses. In either case, you can use fromCharCode() to convert to a string representation. E.g.

```
document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
    var charTyped = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    alert("Character typed: " + charTyped);
};
```

Comment: Can I get the same code on different languages. For example user enter 'g' this mean id = 176 for keyboard. And if user enter 'g' then again id = 176. Or is not possible and keyboard used ASCII code

Comment: That's possible you can get same key i.e g for every key pressed regardless of language.

Comment: how can I make it. Now whit this code who you posted I get different code whit same key on different languages?